# basicHttpBinding to wsHttpBinding over SSL

Tags: wcf, web-services, basichttpbinding, wshttpbinding, wcf-wshttpbinding

Before i have tested one webservice in soapUI its works fine. But now webservice was changed basicHttpBinding to wsHttpBinding over SSL. Now i'm trying to execute the webservice the following exception are im getting.  Im using the webservice url in objective c. I dont how i can test and execute in SOAP UI and iphone now. any one please tel me how i can resolve.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</a:Action>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <s:Code>
            <s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
            <s:Subcode>
               <s:Value>a:DestinationUnreachable</s:Value>
            </s:Subcode>
         </s:Code>
         <s:Reason>
            <s:Text xml:lang="en-AU">The message with To '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.</s:Text>
         </s:Reason>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: I'm not sure But this  [stackoverflow answer][1] may help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27270841/1197132

Answer (score 0):

You have not published your binding configuration. The default WSHttpBinding settings are note interoperable outside WCF (SPNego in the message level). Ine general basic binding is much easier to interoperate.